# Console app error as follows:Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Tags: c#

```
string format="@\"\"\"{0}\"\" \"\"{1}\"\" \"\"{2}\"\"\",Id, ProjectId, refresh";
```

im storing the above as a string and passing it to processstart(appName,format).
the function is as follows.
im getting the mentioned error when passing the arguments

```
public void ProcessStart(string AppName, string format)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[AppName].ToString());
            StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(format);
            StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            Process.Start(StartInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the arguments you are passing in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot add the arguments within the format-string, this should work:

```
string format = "@\"\"\"{0}\"\" \"\"{1}\"\" \"\"{2}\"\"\"";
var args = string.Format(format, Id, ProjectId, refresh);
StartInfo.Arguments = args ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `format string` looks like aggregated string with parameters.

Change your `string` format to:

```
string format="@\"\"\"{0}\"\" \"\"{1}\"\" \"\"{2}\"\"\";
```

and then

```
StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(format, Id, ProjectId, refresh);
```